WordPress commercial theme cancels default functionality
I built a site with a WordPress commercial theme which has prebuilt portfolio-type custom posts. These posts have a couple of preset custom fields from the theme developer, to which I want to add some of my own.
The theme developer told me that this is not available in the theme, neither can I use the custom-field WordPress functionality to create any custom posts of my own from scratch.
In other words, the theme is 'locked' with these specific custom posts and custom fields.
My question is, isn't it unacceptable for a commercial theme to cancel default functionality of WordPress?

in wordpress you can customise everything by creating your own plugins or themes, look here : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/

Yes, I am aware of that, (I also work with code), but I did the previous question in terms of deontology (code of conduct) regarding theme development. A theme is supposed to add to the default functionality of the WordPress platform - not cancel default functionality, or am I wrong? Through the theme settings, custom-field setting is disabled from the theme and it's developer has confirmed this.

a theme is supposed to manage display of the public pages and no more. creating CPT or managing data should be done by plugin then the theme you are speaking about has already a flaw at this step.

It's not really cancelling anything out though - you still have the ability to all of these things with custom code, the developer just hasn't made it straight forward for you to do.  There's always a workaround the question is "Is it worth the effort?"

In my opinion, it is cancelling it, because if a built-in wordpress theme were installed, the admin would have the custom-post-type functionality available and be able to work with it, whereas with this theme installed, this functionality is hidden and the admin needs to have developer capacities in order to tweak the theme files and access this functionality.

There's no quality standard for commercial themes and they frequently engage in bad practices. As a WP dev I personally find it unacceptable, but the only recourse you have is voting with your wallet.
